# can't access array elements in TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, arrays, typescript, drag-and-drop, inertiajs

this is a function that i wrote to get the files inside a folder for dreg and drop box i made for my react app

```
export const traverseDirectory = (
    directory: any,
    file_array:File[],
    path_array:string[]
) => {
    const reader = directory.createReader();
    reader.readEntries((entries: any) => {
        entries.forEach((entry: any) => {
            if (entry.isFile) {
                path_array.push(entry.fullPath);
                entry.file((file: File) => {
                    file_array.push(file);
                });
            } else if (entry.isDirectory) {
                traverseDirectory(entry,file_array,path_array);
            }
        });
    });

    return {
          'files': file_array,
          'paths': path_array,
        }
};
```

and this is how i implement it if item is directory it will try to get files inside the directory(in a seperate file)

```
const items = event.dataTransfer.items;
const entry = item.webkitGetAsEntry();
if (entry) {
// Recursively traverse the directory and collect files
 const data = traverseDirectory(entry, folderFiles, relativePaths);
//1
console.log(data)
//2
console.log(data.files);
//3
console.log(data.files.length);
//4
console.log(data.files[0]);
}
```

and these are the result it gives me
[array conole log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FEECZ.png)
can some one tell me why i can't access the array elements

I trie using useState and rather than retuning object I tried mutate the arrays inside the function nothing worked

Answer (score 0):

An array is a referenced type in javascript. This means that when you log an array that changes its value before you open it in your browser console, it will show you the current value and not the value you had at the time it appeared in your console. As you can see in your first log, the array has the length "0". This is what you saw before you opened the object. The same is true for your second log: the console shows you an empty array because, at the time you logged it, it was actually empty. To avoid this you can do the following: console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(yourValue)))